# How to prompt output to console and appending it to a file at the same time

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I'd like to unify these command in a single row.

```
echo "Hello"
echo "Hello" >> myFile.txt
```

i tried using redirect and output in randoms way, and well, i ve not been lucky ^^

Edit: Need to do this with window cmd.

Any suggestion?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239924/windows-batch-tee-command looks like it's not easily doable without 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no native way to do this. Either you use an external tool like wintee (https://code.google.com/p/wintee/) or you'll have to do something ugly. However, if your only goal is to unify both lines into one, this will work:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET msg=Hello&&ECHO !msg!&&ECHO !msg!>>myFile.txt
```

Or:

```
ECHO Hello&&ECHO Hello>>myFile.txt
```

You can always combine two or more lines of code with `&`or `&&` in batch. `cmd1&cmd2` means "do cmd1 and then cmd2" and `cmd1&&cmd2` means "do cmd1 and if it succeeded do cmd 2".

If you decide to use the first peace option you don't forget that you will need to add `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and adress to your variables using `!...!` instead of `%...%`.

Answer (score 0):

You may create your own "like-**tee.bat**" file in a very simple way:

```
@echo %*
@echo %* > CON
```

... and then use it this way:

```
call tee "Hello" >> myFile.txt
```

Note: you should name your batch file with a name different than "tee.bat" to avoid criticisms from the purists! **`;)`**